# BASH - find and grep specific file in many folders

Tags: bash, grep, find

From the current directory, I try to `find` specific subfolders and `grep` files with specific extension.

**sub-folder structure:**

> ```
> .../1/A
> .../1/B
> .../2/A
> .../2/B
> .../3/A
> .../3/B
> ```

...I want to find each sub-folder contains B in PATH

**desired output:**

> ```
> .../1/B
> .../2/B
> .../3/B
> ```

... in each in this sub-folder (B) I want to run `grep`, but I get no desired output

> ```
> grep -ro '...match_pattern...' .../1/B/*.out
> grep -ro '...match_pattern...' .../2/B/*.out
> grep -ro '...match_pattern...' .../3/B/*.out
> ```

I tried this code, but no luck. Any advise?

```
readarray LIST < <(find . -type d B | cut -c 3- )
for i in "(LIST[@]}"
do
     echo $i/*.out
     grep -ro '...match_pattern...' $i*.out
done
```

I got this and `grep` looking for two file

```
NOK outout     - grep -ro '...match_pattern...' .../1/B /*.out
desired output - grep -ro '...match_pattern...' .../1/B/*.out
```

Comment: `for i in "(LIST[@]}"` is an error; you want `for i in "${LIST[@]}"`. But the entire array indirection is wasteful; don't store things in a variable you only use once.

Answer (score 1):

Using `globstar` option of `bash`, this could be done in a simpler way without resorting to `find` command:

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -o '…PATTERNS…' **/B/*.out
```

Comment: Might want to add `nullglob` yes?

Comment: @Jetchisel If the pattern `**/B/*.out` doesn't match a filename and `nullglob` option is set, then `grep` will be waiting input from `stdin`. Personally I wouldn't want that. In its current form (`nullglob` is unset by default), it will issue a `No such file or directory` message, which I would prefer.

Comment: Right, I forgot that I always add `/dev/null` after `grep` for such rare situations, but of course you're right about not adding nullglob.

Comment: this command works OK: grep -o '…PATTERNS…' **/B/*.out ....but I need PWD, if grep match is not empty - how can I do that?

Comment: @Scripter Do you need the full path? Replace `**/B/*.out` with `"$PWD"/**/B/*.out`

Comment: THANKS, looks like command works now :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
find "$PWD" -name B -type d -print -execdir sh -c 'grep ... *.out' \;
```

where

- `$PWD` is the current directory; can be substituted with `.` or any valid directory
- `-name B` is the name of the item you are looking for
- `-type d` the found item should be a directory
- `-print` optionally print out the "hit"
- `-execdir` **in the directory** execute the following command:
- `sh -c '<script>'` to prevent expansion of wildcard in "script"
- `grep ... *.out` substitute your grep command
- `\;` required terminator for find

*Not sure why you would want to wrap a find in a for loop.*

Comment: This won't work correctly because `*.out` is expanded by the shell before `grep` runs. You can fix that with `-execdir sh -c 'grep ... *.out' \;`

Comment: @tripleee Only if it matches anything in `$PWD/*.out`. Right?

Comment: It depends on your `nullglob` setting; if it is set, a wildcard which doesn't match anything expands to nothing, and if it is unset, you get `grep: *.out: no such file or directory` because you are passing that as the literal file name to `grep` (unless of course a file with precisely that name exists in the target directory).

Comment: FIND command works ok, but GREP not,tripleee has a point - rep: *.out: no such file or directory - how can I prevent wildcard * to expand?

Comment: @Scripter I updated my answer with tripleee's suggestion: `sh -c 'grep ...'`.